# Geom_box plotting "bars" not boxes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a dataset that looks as follows:

[image]

And I am trying to create a boxplot using

```
ggplot(test2, aes(x=GameCondition, y=Alignment.bin, fill = GameCondition)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

However instead of the expected boxplot it creates the following plot:
[image]

Annoyingly, I am unable to replicate this problem because when I use the dummy date

```
test <- data.frame(GameCondition = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
                 Alignment.bin = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1,0, 1,NA))
test$GameCondition <- as.factor(test$GameCondition)
```

with the same code for plotting I get the expected boxes.

[image]

Note that for both data frames the "GameCondition"-variable is a factor and the "Alignment.bin"-factor is dbl.

[image]

What could be the reason why the boxes are not plotted properly when using the data "test2" instead of the data "test"?

Comment: One approach to try and narrow the problem - halve your dataset (by rows) and run the code on each half - if only one experiences the issue then take the problematic half and halve it again, recursively until you have the smallest dataset you can make that duplicates the issue.

Comment: In your dummy data, the Q25, Q50, and Q75 of some of the categories are not exactly equal to 0 or 1. In your real data, all of them are equal to 0 or 1 so the boxes span the entire range of the y-axis.

Comment: I think a boxplot is not the best visualization of this dataset if the only possible values of Alignment.bin are 0, 1, or NA. You might consider a bar plot of counts of 0 and 1 values for each game condition, or even a table with the six count values.

Comment: If, as @qdread says, all of your Alignment.bin values are 0, 1 or NA, then this is the expected result of a boxplot. A boxplot doesn't really make sense for binary data.

Comment: This is a problem with your data, not the code - it is not a "bar", but rather a box spanning the entire range (which reflects your data)

Comment: I appreciate the comments but in the dummy data as well as in the real data all the values are 0, 1 or NA. If this is the expected result of a boxplot (as @Allan Cameron suggest) then why is it not replicated with the dummy data where all the values are also 0, 1 or NA? Why does the real data generate a box spanning the entire range when the dummy data also have only 0 and 1 values?

Comment: @Icewaffle The upper and lower hinges are the first and third quartiles, but if you only have a `c(0, 1)` for your test data, the first and third quartiles are 0.25 and 0.75. You can test this with `quantile(c(0, 1), c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))`. However, if you have lots of 1s and zeros, then the upper and lower quartiles become 0 and 1 (try `quantile(rep(c(0, 1), 50), c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))`). So your test only looks OK because you are showing the quartiles of a length-2 vector, which is of questionable validity and utility.